# Making Dynamicaly Created Taskview Clickable

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

I want to create a Dynamically created Text view Clickable. I have created the Text view based on the result taken from data in a Sqlite table then put the data into Text view. number of Text views increase as more records inserted in the table. Given Bellow is the code for it.

```
ClassInfo[] info =  db.getClassesDetail();
String s = info[0].getClassName()+"   "+ info[0].getSectionName();
```

Array is passed to a method in other class.
    setFrontLayout(info);

The Method for creating the Dynamic Text view based on records in table or simply data in the array.

```
private void setFrontLayout(ClassInfo[] info)
{           
int u = info.length;
int count = 0;
int tvid=1;
while(count < u )
{
String str = "Class : " + info[count].getClassName() +"     " + "Semester : " +     info[count].getSemester()
+ "\n" + "Section : " + info[count].getSectionName() + "        " + "Programm : " +     info[count].getProgName()
+ "\n" + "Department : " + info[count].getDeptName();           
subLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
subLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
subLayout.setPadding(5, 10,5,20);               
tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText(str);
tv.setWidth(400);
tv.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
tv.setPadding(17,3, 15,3);
subLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
subLayout.addView(tv);
parentLayout.addView(subLayout);
count++;
}
```

Now what i want is to attach clicklistener to these created Text views by making it clickable to direct to a new activity. i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: The point is to create an intent and call a start activity method in the onclick listener. If you use an array adapter anytime the results changes... your view changes. Check my answer and let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

Not got Eclipse running so I can't check, but setting an on click listener should work.

```
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //Code here 
        }
    });
```

Comment: yes setting click listener can be added this way. but as you can see the code the text view is added in a loop based on the number of records so how do i attach click listener to a multiple text views that is created by one line of code?

Comment: Surly a listview would be a better way of solving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array adapter.
The idea is, for each entry you draw your text view.
Then register an onclick listener and send and intent with the class info (so... be sure it implements Parcelable or Serializable).
Create an activity which renders that info and register the intent in your manifest.

```
public class ClassInfoArrayListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ClassInfo> {

public ClassInfoArrayListAdapter (Context context, int resource, List<ClassInfo> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);

    ClassInfo classInfo = getItem(position);

    TextView classTextVIew = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.className);
    classTextVIew.setText(classInfo.getUuid().toString());

    classTextVIew.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent= new Intent();
            intent.setAction("your.package.SHOW_CLASS_INFO");
            intent.putExtra("classInfo", classInfo);

            parent.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rowView;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i managed to make it work by adding a few lines of code. by assigning an id to text view with every iteration and then setting on click listener in every iteration.
    'tv.setId(tvid+1);'
    'tv.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);'

Comment: I don't get your solution but this MainActivity.this seems a bad practice.

Comment: how should i use it then?

Comment: Post your new code but... like I said if you want to show an activity you should send an intent with a startActivity method.

Comment: lets say for example that the text views created above , as they are created dyanmicaly , multiple text views with one line of code in a loop. now that the text views are created, i want the text views to be clickable for the purpose lets say to copy the text in text view to an edit text in the same activity, forget about calling to another activity, attaching on click listener to the text views for the purpose of some action in the same activity , is there any way to do so? look the code above

Comment: You want in the same activity to show the entries (with a loop) and to manage onclick so, if you click on one row then another thing in the view changes its content. Am I right? Now I get the MainActivity.this.

Comment: Yes. but as you can see the text views are created dynamicaly so i cant attach onclick listener to each activity separately. is there any way to do that

Comment: I don't get you really... how many activities do you have? Give more information please.

Comment: If you want to use this method in different activities then pass the activity like an argument... but I think is better the array adapter approach.